# Onepage success page source

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to add some google tracking scripts to onepage success.

But I'm facing a problem in this page.. the url is :

checkout/onepage/success/

but when I click on view page source in my browser it's redirect me to another page :

checkout/cart/

Could you please help ? how I can stop this redirect ?

Please note that I'm using custom theme.

Looking forward for your quick assistance.

Comment: There a extensions that allow you to test https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_CheckoutTester2/blob/master/USAGE.md

Comment: Adding tracking scripts and testing your success page will become unmanageable over time. You should consider using a third-party extension. eg https://github.com/magepal/magento2-google-tag-manager and https://github.com/magepal/magento2-preview-checkout-success-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct behavior, the system clear quote data on success page

Just for temporary development purposes you can comment `clearQuote` in `Success` action

See `\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success`

```
        $session->clearQuote();
```

Comment: I will check and let you know

Comment: You're right, it's works now.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you do not need to view source to add Google scripts to Magento. In the Admin area, under `Stores -> Configuration`, click on `Sales -> Google API`. There you can paste your Google Analytics Tracking ID (Usually begins with `UA-.....`) under the heading `Account Number`.

If the script is to be added only to a specific page, then you will need to 
[Insert a JS component in the proper PHTML template](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html).

Comment: No this scripts should be added only in the success page. It's related to conversions