# Adding tracking code to success page

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to add tracking code to my onepage success page.
I've created layout and created success.phtml to my custom theme.
app/design/frontend/my_theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <script src="module-checkout::templates/success.phtml"/>
</head>
```

app/design/frontend/my_theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml

```
my tracking code
```

Everything fine but the tracking code didn't appear when I click view page source in my browser !

Could you please help me.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot use something like View Page Source for Success page, because the browser will try to load page one more time for receive source and will redirect to cart or home page instead. You can use Inspect logic or use temporary workaround from https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/357279/91782
2. You have incorrect layout definition. Looks like you are trying to add phtml `block`, but using `script` directive for. You need something like:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceContainer name="after_body_start">
               <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" name="your_tracking_code" template="Magento_Checkout::success.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
           </referenceContainer>
       </body>
   </page>
   ```

   Where I suggest to create custom block instead of `Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success` to receive current order data. See `Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success` as example how to receive current order data. You should define custom template instead of `Magento_Checkout::success.phtml` in the same format.

   I hope you can see some manuals or example in Magento code

Comment: Thanks a lot victor, but I found the solution. there is another success.phtml in Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend and that was the file which I've to update